# New Zealand Visitor Visa refusal?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, new-zealand

We are from Sri Lanka. My wife applied to New Zealand twice and got refused along with me as her dependent. Now we are in Sweden as my wife is studying at a Swedish university. I want to travel to NZ as a tourist while my wife stays in Sweden. We do not have much strong background to show. But I'm a genuine visitor and want to return to my wife upon completion of my visit. But many say its a risk to apply to NZ again with my previous refusals. Because if I'm to apply again, I have to pay for a visa consultant and lose money. Both visas lodge by unlicenced consultants( we didn't know it was a must) and the reasons for refusals are very simple.

1. How can I prove that I'm a genuine visitor ? I don't have much wealth back home or in Sweden. But clearly I can fund my trip. I have got my Swedish ID, new part time job(I pay taxes) and bank accounts.

   2. Are there any chances of being refused again due to my history?
   3. Are there any things I should know of before applying?

Answer (score 1):

Consultant or not, the onus of all information provided is on the applicant, in eyes of Visa Officer. Using licensed/unlicensed/any consultant does not effect visa officer's decision.

Visa officer tries to find the answer to few following question:

- why this person will not over stay his/her visa duration?
- What will compel him/her to come out of Visa Officer's country? Job? How much is the income now? Can he earn more in country X by legal/illegal means?
- How much money this typical holiday costs?
- How is he managing this money? From where he is getting? Is it his own? Parked?
- is it normal in his financial circumstances to spend x amount for money on this holiday? Can he afford this?
- Ho will he be affected (good or bad) in home country if he does not come back? Job loss? Separation from Family? His Living Standards in Home v/s possible living standards in this country?